# Firebase > Running robo test doesn't get past initial screen

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-test-lab

I'm attempting to run [Firebase's `robo test`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test) for a `react-native` `0.52.0` phone app (android apk / no test script)... unfortunately the `robo test` doesn't get past the first page.

I've read that adding `testID` fields was required by other automation frameworks to discover components/buttons, so I tried using [react-native-testid](https://github.com/isnifer/react-native-testid)), but this had no effect. I've also read that `resource-id` should be used instead (but it's not currently supported by react-native?).

Does anyone know why Firebase can't "find" the navigation buttons?

#### Firebase - Known Issues

> Robo test is only compatible with apps that use UI elements from the Android UI framework (including View and ViewGroup objects, but excluding WebView objects). If you use Robo test to exercise apps that use other UI frameworks, including apps that use the Unity game engine, the test may exit without exploring beyond the first screen.

(thanks @Phix)

... however I **assume** react-native would compile/package using "UI elements from the Android UI framework".

#### Other Notes

I'm hoping that a Firebase developer will see this and respond... (["Here at Firebase, we’re big React fans ... If you’re running into issues, open up a question on Stackoverflow, we monitor the Firebase tag closely"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html))

#### Links

- [Firebase's `robo test`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test)
- [The beginners guide to React Native and Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html)
- [SO > How to use firebase TestLab with react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360389/how-to-use-firebase-testlab-with-react-native)
- [RN > Does React Native use non-native UI elements (Android)?](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/does-react-native-use-non-native-ui-elements-android/9580?u=nickg)
- [RN > resource-id should be set automatically with a reliable pattern](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/resource-id-should-be-set-automatically-with-a-reliable-pattern)
- [RN > Add support for resource-id](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-support-for-resource-id)

Comment: Just making sure you saw this part of the docs: `If you use Robo test to exercise apps that use other UI frameworks, including apps that use the Unity game engine, the test may exit without exploring beyond the first screen.`

Comment: Interesting... no I hadn't (thanks)... however I assume react-native would compile/package using "UI elements from the Android UI framework"... :/ .

Comment: I work on the Robo at Firebase. Thanks for doing the research and compiling informative links! Are you trying to specify login and password for Robo to get past the login screen? If so, From [this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9777), it looks like we should make Robo use "contentDescription" (in addition to resource-id) to identify input text boxes. Could you try uiautomatorviewer, which comes part of Android SDK, on the screen with login/password input boxes and check if they have different "contentDescription". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Test Lab currently doesn't support anything but native apps that use native Android views and widgets (as you have seen in the documentation).

If you have a feature request, [please file one](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).